# SML: What does this this function guess : bool * ('a * 'a) -> 'a * 'a calculate?

Tags: sml

From an old exam I had this SML function and I should give an answer on what this function calculates.

`fun guess(e,(a,b)) = if e then (a,b) else (b,a)`

The signature is `bool * ('a * 'a) -> 'a * 'a` but I have no clue what the purpose of this function is - despite the fact that it returns either (a,b) or (b,a).
Can anyone light me up?

Comment: Why do you think that the function had any purpose beyond being an example for an exam question? By the way -- edit your question so that bool appears highlighted as well.

Comment: I was a bit irritated by the question on what the function does calculate and it it has a higher meaning.

Comment: The question seemed like an intentionally easy one in a Programming Languages course over the section on functional programming. I've been on the teacher end of the equation and know from experience that a great many undergraduate CS students struggle to wrap their Java-warped minds around things like Lisp or ML. On exams I often give a number of easy questions (in addition to some more challenging ones) in order to make the test more passable for the majority.

Comment: Indeed this is from an exam from the lecture on fundamentals of programming languages - with sml as lang for functional pogramming.
And yes, coming from the object-orientiented/iterative programming way to a recursive functional way is a bit challening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the condition is true it leaves (a,b) alone, otherwise it reverses it. There really isn't anything more to say about what it computes. As to borderline plausible motivation, sometimes ordered pairs need to be sorted in various ways. For example, `guess(a<=b,(a,b))` will reverse (a,b) if a > b.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Okay this seems to be a plausible answer to the question. I just will accept it as a simple example function.